# Метод класса в запросе к базе данных SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3

class Transport(object):
    '''transport_type: str
    colour: str
    volume: float'''
    def __init__(self, transport_type, colour, volume):
        self.transport_type = transport_type
        self.colour = colour
        self.volume = volume

    def getType(self):
        return self.transport_type

    def getColour(self):
        return self.colour

    def getVolume(self):
        return self.volume

class Tax(object):
    '''tax_amount: int
    tax_due_date: str'''
    def __init__(self, tax_amount, tax_due_date):
        self.tax_amount = tax_amount
        self.tax_due_date = tax_due_date

    def getTaxAmount(self):
        return self.tax_amount

    def getTaxDueDate(self):
        return self.tax_due_date

transport = Transport('Car', 'Black', 3.5)
#transport.transport_type = "Car"
#transport.colour = "Black"
#transport.volume = 3.5
tax = Tax(10000, '18.10.2019')
#tax.tax_amount = 10000
#tax.tax_due_date = '18.10.2019'

conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
c = conn.cursor()
#c.execute('''CREATE TABLE transportlist (transport_type text, colour text, volume real, tax_amount integer, tax_due_date text)''')
c.execute("INSERT INTO transportlist VALUES({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4})".format(transport.getType, transport.getColour, transport.getVolume, tax.getTaxAmount, tax.getTaxDueDate))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Какой текст ошибки?

Comment: File "c:/Users/User/Desktop/unitled.py", line 46, in <module>
    tax.getTaxAmount, tax.getTaxDueDate))
    c.execute("INSERT INTO transportlist VALUES({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4})".format(transport.getType, transport.getColour, transport.getVolume, tax.getTaxAmount, tax.getTaxDueDate))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "<": syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Ну смотрите, чтобы вызвать метод объекта, нужно записать его со скобками.

Вот так:

```
transport.getType()
```

а вы в строку с запросом передаёте методы без скобок, и интерпретатор вместо того, чтобы вызвать их и результаты их вызова вставить строку, просто пытается привести к строковому виду сам метод.

В итоге у вас в строке с запросом получается что-то такое:

```
INSERT INTO transportlist VALUES(<bound method Transport.getType of <__main__.Transport object at 0x7f5acabf3b38>>, <bound method Transport.getColour of <__main__.Transport object at 0x7f5acabf3b38>>, <bound method Transport.getVolume of <__main__.Transport object at 0x7f5acabf3b38>>, <bound method Tax.getTaxAmount of <__main__.Tax object at 0x7f5acabf3b70>>, <bound method Tax.getTaxDueDate of <__main__.Tax object at 0x7f5acabf3b70>>)
```

Соответственно, если вы допишите скобки к каждому методу, то будет вам счастье.

PS: И ещё. Вообще, формировать строку sql-запроса с помощью `format` или конкатенации отдельных частей этой строки - довольно плохая практика, которая может привести к серьёзным проблемам. Безопасным способом делать это, является передача параметров в качестве аргументов метода `execute`.

Подробнее можно прочитать, например, здесь: http://python-3.ru/page/parameterized-queries-sqlite-python